# Get notified of Subversion conflicts across branches

Tags: svn, repository, conflict

We are using a fairly standard Subversion process of branching from trunk on a feature and then merging back in when the feature is complete. Merges sometimes end up in conflicts and we would like to be proactive.

In general we would like to know if anyone else is working on the same file during a time window. Basically we are looking for a way to scan across a limited number of branches and get notified if more than one person touched the same file or a section of a file.

I've searched but could not find a tool like this. Is anyone aware of anything similar we might be able to use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try locking the file when you work on it. It will error out only during the commit. Not while the other person checkout and makes his changes. But you can use the svn list command to see if the file is locked before you even make your changes. Locked files will be have  a prefix O.

Comment: Thank you. That would not quite work I believe as these two files would be on different branches